# How to specify a type a action to trigger on alerts?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to integrate alerts in my script, but I see no possibility to choose for the action triggered by the alerts (i.e, notify on the app, show on the popup, sending a mail etc.)

```
//@version=5
strategy("test 3", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, calc_on_every_tick=true, initial_capital=500, default_qty_value = 500, currency='USD', process_orders_on_close=true, commission_type='percent', commission_value=0.075, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, calc_on_order_fills=true)


// retrieve Heikin Ashi values
haHandle=ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,open)
haClose=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,close)
haDeltaAbs=haClose-haClose[1]
haDeltaRel=haDeltaAbs/haClose[1]*100


// Trade Entry
haEntryCondition=haDeltaRel>0 and haDeltaRel[1]<0
strategy.entry("trade", strategy.long, when = haEntryCondition)

// Trade Exit
haThreshold = -0.5
haExitCondition=haDeltaRel<haThreshold
strategy.close("trade", when = haExitCondition)


// Alerts

if(haEntryCondition)
    alert("ENTRY", freq=alert.freq_all)

if(haExitCondition)
    alert("EXIT", freq=alert.freq_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that programmatically.

If you want to have different actions for different alerts, you can use `alertcondition()` and name an alert. Then you can individually select an alert from the drop-down menu and its action while creating an alert.